# MVVM for third party WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

We are using a third party Chart control which was developed using WPF and that doesn't support MVVM. Now we need to add few more functionality and that should support Add/Remove feature on demand. We need to create Wrapper Chart control with new features and that should support MVVM. This dll/Module will be used by a few other Modules/Projects.

Note : 
  For every new feature we created Handler and composed the existing chart control. So we were able to support add/remove feature on demand.

Question :
    How to support MVVM, is it for each FeatureHandler should i create ViewModel which wrap FeatureHandler(View) and looks like MVVM? Need clarification on this part.....

Comment: What is `FeatureHandler`? What chart are you using?

Comment: @ColinE : All new feature are wrapped with FeatureHandler classes, Like ZoomFeatureHandler...., We are using Chart which was built by ohter team from our company.

Comment: What does the chart control exposes as properties and how do you implement it ? provide a simple case snippet code regardless of MVVM pattern. "Your issue is pretty specific, you may discuss with your company's team about this"

Comment: Why down vote? what is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean dosen't support MVVM? I sounds fairly unlikely that a chart control developed with WPF dosen't expose properties in form of dependency properties. Do you have link to this third party chart control?

Comment: Your guess is correct, ChartControl doesn't expose Dependency properties, rather it exposes Properties like Precision, OffSet,....

Comment: Ok, so I think the best you can do is to wrap the control and expose dependency properties. With dependency properties you enable data binding and then it's possible to use the MVVM design pattern.